# Glitch fix for chosen multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qszyz5eg/)

### Description:

1. I have applied **chosen** plugin for a **multiselect** dropdown
2. The first option is "**Any**"
3. Those who are accustomed with **chosen** dropdown,they know that when an option is selected(from **chosen multiselect**) and presented in the **dropdown textarea**-like field, you will see it disabled from the list menu automatically.
4. When the first option "**Any**" is be selected, then all the other options from the list menu is also **disabled**.
5. When the "**Any**" option is removed from the **dropdown textarea**-like field(deleting by **clicking** on the **cross** with the selected option),then again all the options are **enabled**.

### Requirement:

1. If we select any option from the **dropdown**, then its presented in the **textarea**-like filed, denoting that its being **selected**.
2. First select any option except "**Any**".
3. It will be displayed on the **textarea**-like field.
4. Now Select "**Any**".
5. **Any** will be displayed in the textarea-like field, and the previously selected option(s) is also being displayed in the **textarea**-like field.
6. I need the previously options selected to be removed from the **textarea**-field

How can I achieve this `functionality`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define what happens in your `if statement` that checks to see if the `Any` option is selected

```
if (params.selected && params.selected == "Any") {
    // disable the select
    $('.chosen-select').val('Any'); // Select Any and remove everything else
```

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qszyz5eg/1/)